# Making a responsive profile picture

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

So I am building a `nav` menu that ,when opened, reveals your menu as well as your name, email and your profile picture.The problem I am facing is that when users upload their profile pictures (which often differ in width and height) and using a border radius, I get undesirable results. What would look fine on desktop, looks horrible on mobile.
See code below:

```
$menu = "<nav id='menu'>
                         <ul>
                                                        <li><table border='0' width='100%%'>
                                                        <tr>
                                                        <td rowspan='2' style='width:30%;height:100%;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:5px;'><div style=\"display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:url('" .$mem_avatar."')\"></div></td>
                                                        <td style='70%; padding-left:5px;'><ul><li><h2>$mem_name $mem_surname</h2></li><li ><h4>$mem_email</h4></li></ul></td>

                                                        </tr>
                                                        </table>
```

I would like to fix it so that when someone uploads their picture, it will display properly on both desktop and mobile platforms.The above will work fine on a picture on desktop but would be terribly squashed on mobile. I have tried using the `width: 10vw` `height:10vw` and this would also look fine on desktop but way to small on mobile. When making the value higher, the result would be a reverse, what looks good on mobile would look horrible on desktop

Comment: Many platforms (check Twitter, LinkedIn and even StackOverflow) use a cut-out for the profile picture, so all of them have the same ratio.

Comment: @GolezTrol Could you specify what you mean with cutouts?

Comment: Trimming the edges to make a uniform shape (often it's square, but any other ratio would do too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap, instead of common CSS.
It will provide you, ready-made classes as per your requirements.
In Bootstrap, responsive images automatically adjust to fit the size of the screen.

Create responsive images by adding an `.img-responsive` class to the `<img>` tag. The image will then scale nicely to the parent element.

The `.img-responsive` class applies `display: block;` and `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania">
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Could you show me how I would go about doing this. Should I remove the div completely?

Comment: You need to link bootstrap min.css & min.js files within your <head>...</head> Then within div i.e <div class="img-responsive"> ...</div>

Comment: Well all the linking has already been done. However currently I have the image displayed as a background-image in css. Should I change this?

Comment: tried adding the class `img-responsive` however the picture fails to display on both desktop and mobile

Comment: you can use background-size: cover CSS property. or if you want to stretch the background-image with resize in the div, use background-size: 100% 100%

Comment: Still not working, mind if we engage in pm's to solve this?